# How to use micro-ROS for an Arduino DUE

Tags: ros2, micro-ros

As the question states, I'm trying to get micro-ROS on an Aruino-DUE. I know it isn't an officially supported board, but it does have community support however I can't figure out how to install that version of micro-ROS. I'm very new so sorry if this is an obvious answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should setup micro-ros-setup on your ubuntu computer, and also download arduino ide image, download micro-ros-arduino library into the arduino ide, and try upload example to arduino due, if you want do with video I made a video about how to use micro-ros with esp32 board.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ggxNLKZqITU

Comment: I don't have an esp32 board though. Will this still work for Arduino Due?

Comment: Sure it will work

Comment: sorry for the super late response, this worked! Thank you!